# What is the difference between the following prepositions:

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

"He is the best player of the country."
and
"He is the best player in the country."

When should we use "of" and when should we use "in"?

Comment: Can you add some examples from well-written sources (linked and attributed), please? One sounds far less natural to my ears than the other. And [these Google 5-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=best+player+of+the+country%2Cbest+player+in+the+country&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbest%20player%20in%20the%20country%3B%2Cc0) also seem to suggest strongly that '[the] best player of the country' is unidiomatic.

Comment: Like at the end of a boxing match the commentator says "he is still the heavy weight champion of the world". Or the phrase "all the countries in the world" not "of the world". 

What about this one: "she is the best teacher in/of the institute." I think "in" sounds better here but I'm not sure why

Comment: @Levi in "he is still the Heavyweight Champion of the World",  *Heavyweight Champion of the World* is a fixed title. (Of - preposition ≈ associated in some way with.)  In "He is the best player in the country." = "... within/inside the country" and "within/inside the country" is an adjectival phrase describing "player" - it is not a title.